# Decrypt many PDFs in one go using pdftk

Tags: unix, pdftk

I have 10 PDFs that ask for a user password to open. I know that password. I want to keep them in a decrypted format. Their filenames follow the form: 
static_part.dynamic_part_like_date.pdf

I want to convert all the 10 files. I can give a * after the static part and work on all of them, but I also want the corresponding output filenames. So there has to be a way to capture the dynamic part of the filename and then use it in the output filename.

The normal way of doing this for one file is:

pdftk secured.pdf input_pw foopass output unsecured.pdf

I want to do something like:

pdftk var=secured*.pdf input_pw foopass output unsecured+var.pdf

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your request is a little ambiguous, but here are some ideas that might help you.

Assuming 1 of your 10 files is

```
  # static_part.dynamic_part_like_date.pdf
  # SalesReport.20110416.pdf  (YYYYMMDD)
```

And you want only the SalesReport.pdf converted as unsecured, you can use a shell script  to achieve your requirement:

```
# make a file with the following contents, 
# then make it executable with `chmod 755 pdfFixer.sh`
# the .../bin/bash has to be the first line the file.

$ cat pdfFixer.sh

#!/bin/bash

# call the script like $ pdfFixer.sh staticPart.*.pdf  
# ( not '$' char in your command, that is the cmd-line prompt in this example,
#   yours may look different )

# use a variable to hold the password you want to use
pw=foopass

for file in ${@} ; do

    # %%.* strips off everything after the first '.' char
    unsecuredName=${file%%.*}.pdf

    #your example : pdftk secured.pdf input_pw foopass output unsecured.pdf
    #converts to
    pdftk ${file} input_pw ${foopass} output ${unsecuredName}.pdf
done
```

You may find that you need to modify the `%.*` thing to

- strip less from end, (use %.*) to strip just the last '.' and all chars after (strip from right).
- strip from the fron (use #*.) to just the static part, leaving the dynamic part OR
- strip from the front (use ##*.) to strip everything until the last '.' char.

It will really be much easier for you to figure out what you need at the cmd-line.
Set a variable with 1 sample fileName

```
myTestFileName=staticPart.dynamicPart.pdf
```

and then use echo combined with the variable modifiers to see the results.

```
echo ${myTestFileName##*.}
echo ${myTestFileName#*.}
echo ${myTestFileName##.*}
echo ${myTestFileName#.*}
echo ${myTestFileName%%.*}
```

etc.

Also notice how I combine a modified variable value with a plain string (.pdf), in `unsecuredName=${file%%.*}.pdf`

IHTH

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't tried your solution. Also I would like a one line command instead of a shell script. Thanks for the effort and the answer.